# Extending JPA to WebServices

Tags: java, jpa, repository-pattern

After reading some pages from DDD, I read about Repository pattern, then used it in an application successfully (I really liked it); then I noticed that `EntityManager` is `generic-repository-like`, but while I was reading about Repository I saw many examples on the web explaining how to impliment Repository pattern, and JPA was a simple Repository implementation between many implementations, like this website: http://www.lestard.eu/2015/generic_repository_part1/

The developer demonstrated in-memory implementations of Repository pattern, and in the second part : http://www.lestard.eu/2015/generic_repository_part2/, showed JPA implementation of repository pattern.

So here my question: while JPA is already like a generic repository, can we extend JPA to use in-memory, web services (e.g: REST CRUD) and entity persisting -- as JPA stands for Java PERSISITENCE API, (I wrote it in capital letters to show that it means a general persistence mechanism) -- as it seems that current JPA is tightly coupled with databases, but its name refer to a general use.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's possible but I would prefer not to do this and don't have any links to specific implementation standard (like Java JPA). I prefer to hide all of implementation details inside my `Repository` impl.

Moreover, I *definitely don't like* idea to put any persisting (like `@Entity`) or conversion (like `@XmlRootElement` from JAXB or `@JsonProperty`) annotations inside my domain objects.

The reason is the simple: if in the future you will change Java JPA to smth new like *Java New JPA* you'll have to change you domain objects for this too. But it contradicts whole DDD idea.

Comment: You cans make a difference between mapped object and domain object.

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill sure. Practically, I have e.g. `SettlementMessageEntity` class for persisting (with annotations, some additional `id` fields etc.) and `SettlementMessage` as a domain object. But here is another problem: conversion from entities to DDO and vice versa.

Comment: it envloves more complixity to the project :/

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill you are right but this approach is more flexible: you have your domain model objects and you have DTOs for storing model into DB and you have transformer from DOs to DTOs (here, actually, you can do some transformation e.g. from DOs graph into plain DB records or so). Moreover, you can develop your model and persisting part in parallel in your team.

Comment: of course, that what i was thinking for, for that i asked if we could just have one layer for persistence (JPA), better than making new layer which already includes another layer (JPA).